# Unity WebGL input not recognizing button inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

When I enter play mode on my computer, I am able to press a key and make a game object disappear. I use the OnFire() method that comes with the new input system.

When I export to WebGL and press the same key, nothing happens. These are some of my build settings, not sure if I should look at something else as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What “key” did you pick and had you clicked on the game on the web page before trying?

Comment: I use the OnFire() method that comes with the new input system. It should work when I click or when I press enter.

Comment: And did you click on the game first? To bring it to focus

Comment: Yes I did, to start the game I have to click on a start button and it works, after that, it doesn’t recognize the click or enter key

Comment: Well without proof of Setup your problem isn’t recreatable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually WebGL is one of the least supported platforms, so it's possible they've created the new Input system but haven't optimized it well for WebGL yet.
Either wait for an update (not recommended), or try to convert your project to the old Input system.
I know it's inconvenient, but if it works on your platform, and it doesn't on WebGL, the only realistic assumption is that they haven't updated it yet, and who knows how long it will take ...

However to validate my hypothesis, you can try the other events of the new input system. See if those work.

I am sorry.
Good work